# Why does pip (using --find-links) still collect some dependencies from the internet despite a wheel existing for it in multi-stage docker build?

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile where I build wheels for my project's dependencies in a `python` image, then copy the wheels over to an alpine image and do a `pip install -r ./wheels/requirements.txt --find-links ./wheels`.

It seems to install from most wheels, except certain deps like `numpy`, `spacy`, and `gensim` where it reaches out to the internet to collect their zips/tars.  Why can't pip find the links for them? The wheels are there.  Normally it's whatever, but installing these deps on alpine takes a *very long time*.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.10 as builder
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /wheels

COPY ./requirements.txt /wheels/
RUN pip install -U pip \
    && pip wheel -r ./requirements.txt

FROM python:3.6.10-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache \
            --upgrade \
            --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
        make \
        automake \
        gcc \
        g++ \
        subversion \
        python3-dev \
        gettext \
        libpq \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY --from=builder /wheels /wheels
RUN pip install -U pip \
   && pip install -r ./wheels/requirements.txt --find-links ./wheels \
   && rm -rf /wheels \
   && rm -rf /root/.cache/pip/*


WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app

COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And my requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.2.3
Django==3.0.2
luhn==0.2.0
nltk==3.4.5
numpy==1.18.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
pytest==5.3.5
pytz==2019.3
spacy==2.2.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
yapf==0.29.0
gensim==3.8.1
```

Here's an example log output:

```
Looking in links: ./wheels
Processing /wheels/asgiref-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /wheels/Django-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /wheels/luhn-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /wheels/nltk-3.4.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy==1.18.1
  Downloading numpy-1.18.1.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Processing /wheels/psycopg2-2.8.4-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Processing /wheels/pytest-5.3.5-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /wheels/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting spacy==2.2.3
  Downloading spacy-2.2.3.tar.gz (5.9 MB)
```

Basically I want `numpy` and `spacy` to be processed like Django and the other deps straight from the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy), [`spacy`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy) and [`genism`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim) are all packages combining Python and Cython and that interface with C/C++. In "plain" ([glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) based) Linux distributions, these packages are precompiled to wheel binaries, which are downloaded and installed directly by pip.

However, on Alpine Linux, these packages are not available in their binary form, and must be compiled from source on the Alpine target during install.

The reason for this is that the wheel build system ([PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517)) does not support Alpine Linux. Linux wheel binaries are built for the `manylinux` target, which is not compatible with [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org) based targets, such as Alpine and Void Linux. There's no wheel tag for Alpine, so even if you have a prebuilt Alpine wheel, you can't install its directly using pip. Instead, pip has to fetch the package source code and build it on the target.

The other packages are pure Python, so they are used as provided.

You can find more details on this issue, as well as the current status, in the following PyPa GitHub thread:
https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/issues/37

Comment: I ended up switching my runtime image to `ubuntu:bionic` as an alternative to the python alpine image (for those interested in another option).  It's working well